# Finding Column number in CSV using python

Tags: python, csv

I want to match a certain string in a CSV file and return the `column` of the string within the CSV file for example

```
import csv
data = ['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['h','i','j']
```

for example I'm looking for the word `e`, I want it to return [1] as it is in the second column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why do you need `csv` in this example.

```
>>> data = ['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['h','i','j']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> string = 'e'
>>> for idx, lst in enumerate(data):
...     if string in lst:
...             print idx

1
```

Comment: works great thanks. Working with a much bigger dataset just needed some guidance on how it worked.

Comment: @wolendranh: I think you return the index of a row (instead of column).

Comment: @abukaj this is idex of element. It could be same approach for csv colums, a bit modified.

Comment: @wolendranh: I know, but it is index of the `lst` in `data`, not of `string` in the `lst` (which in case of csv data would be the column number).

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `csv.reader` object and `enumerate` function(to get key/value sequence):

```
def get_column(file, word):
    with open(file) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            for k,v in enumerate(row):
                if v == word:
                    return k  # immediate value return to avoid further loop iteration

search_word = 'e'
print(get_column("data/sample.csv", search_word))  # "data/sample.csv" is an exemplary file path
```

The output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
>>> data_list = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['h','i','j']] 
>>> col2_list = []
>>> 
>>> for d in data_list:
...     col2=d[1]
...     col2_list.append(col2)
```

So in the end you get a list with all the values of column [1]:

```
col2_list = ["b","e","i"]
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation of wolendranh's answer:

```
>>> data = ['a','b','c'],['d','e','f'],['h','i','j']
>>> word = 'e'
>>> for row in data:
...     try:
...         print(row.index(word))
...     except ValueError:
...         continue
```